# The localized attribute of aui input generated with liferay auto fields not working

Tags: javascript, localization, liferay, liferay-aui

I've used Liferay's AutoFields JavaScript module to dynamically create AUI inputs (text). The rows and the AUI inputs are creating dynamically and it appears to work correctly.

The AUI inputs are localized and must have the attribute `localized="true"` so it can accept both French and English.

The flag whichever flag is set on the first input is automatically set on the dynamic second one.

The issue is that one any of the dynamically created inputs the localization can't change (flag can't be clicked).

Here is the code:

```
    <div class="lfr-form-row lfr-form-row-inline field-wrapper clearfix col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <div class="row-fields">
             <aui:row>
                 <aui:column cssClass="field-wrapper clearfix col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <aui:input fieldParam='filtreTitre0' id='filtreTitre0' name="filtreTitre0" label="value" type="text" localized="true" />
                </aui:column>
                <aui:column cssClass="field-wrapper clearfix col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <aui:input fieldParam='filtreCode0' id='filtreCode0' name="filtreCode0" label="ma.alten.cpm.code" type="text" />
                    <p style="display:none;">code already exist</p>               
                </aui:column>
            </aui:row>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the script:

```
<aui:script use="liferay-auto-fields">
new Liferay.AutoFields(
    {
         contentBox: '#fields-wraper',
         fieldIndexes: '<portlet:namespace />rowIndexes',
         on: {
                'init':function(event) {

                },
                'clone': function(event) {
                    console.log(event);
                AUI().use('aui-form-validator', function(A) {
                    var addedElementCode = A.one('#<portlet:namespace />filtreCode'+event.guid);
                    var addedElementTitle = A.one('#<portlet:namespace />filtreTitre'+event.guid);
                    addedElementTitle.set('value', "");
                    addedElementCode.get('parentNode').get('parentNode').one('p').setStyle('display','none');
                });
                },
                'delete': function(event) {

                }
            }
    }
).render();
</aui:script>
```

Here is a screenshot that illustrates the problem:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors in the browser console?

Comment: @stiemannkj1, there are no errors.

Comment: What version of Liferay are you running and what is your patch level?

Comment: i'm using Liferay 6.2. what do you mean by patch level ?

Comment: Liferay has major and minor releases.  For example Liferay 6.2 is the release.  Liferay releases fixes for bugs through service packs and hot fixes.  These are only provided to EE / DXP customers, and they don't change the release, but they do increase the "patch level".  Again only in EE.  In the community addition there are "general releases".  For example Liferay 6.1 GA1 is the same "release version" as 6.1 GA5 but GA5 has more bug fixes (was released latter than GA1).  On enterprise you dont need to wait for a general release you can download a fix pack.

Comment: If you still need this fixed, let me know.  I have reached out on the Liferay JIRA and Slack channel to see what expected behavior is.  There is a JIRA bug that I believe fixes this but I don't think there is any more general releases for 6.2 and if you arent EE you wont get a service pack (bug wont be fixed for you). Give me another day to discuss this on with Liferay and if they aren't backporting the fix Ill write a solution right here for you.